# What are the steps to establish a client connection to DYDX using Python?

Tags: python, web3py

I'm getting this error when I try to make a client connection to DYDX. I have included all the necessary api_keys and the host.

`Error connecting to client:  'Eth' object has no attribute 'defaultAccount'`

The following is the code for creating a client connection to dydx

```
from dydx3 import Client
from web3 import Web3

from constants import (
    HOST,
    DYDX_API_KEY,
    DYDX_API_SECRET,
    DYDX_API_PASSPHRASE,
    ETH_PRIVATE_KEY,
    STARK_PRIVATE_KEY,
    HTTP_PROVIDER
)

def connect_dydx():

    # Create client connection
    client = Client(
        host=HOST,
        api_key_credentials={
            "key": DYDX_API_KEY,
            "secret": DYDX_API_SECRET,
            "passphrase": DYDX_API_PASSPHRASE
        },
        stark_private_key=STARK_PRIVATE_KEY,
        eth_private_key=ETH_PRIVATE_KEY,
        web3=Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(HTTP_PROVIDER)),
        
    )


    # Confirm Client
    account = client._private.get_account()
    account_id = account.data["account"]["id"]
    quote_balance = account.data["account"]["quoteBalance"]

    print("Connection Successful")
    print("Account ID: ", account_id)
    print("Quote Balance: ", quote_balance)

    return client
```

And this is for the `main.py`

```
from connection import connect_dydx

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    # Connect to client
    try:
        client = connect_dydx()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Error connecting to client: ", e)
        exit(1)
```

I've tried to update the packages and libraries but nothing has worked yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the default example: https://github.com/dydxprotocol/dydx-v3-python/blob/master/examples/onboard.py

```
'''Example for onboarding an account and accessing private endpoints.

Usage: python -m examples.onboard
'''

from dydx3 import Client
from dydx3.constants import API_HOST_GOERLI
from dydx3.constants import NETWORK_ID_GOERLI
from web3 import Web3

# Ganache test address.
ETHEREUM_ADDRESS = '0x22d491Bde2303f2f43325b2108D26f1eAbA1e32b'

# Ganache node.
WEB_PROVIDER_URL = 'http://localhost:8545'

client = Client(
    network_id=NETWORK_ID_GOERLI,
    host=API_HOST_GOERLI,
    default_ethereum_address=ETHEREUM_ADDRESS,
    web3=Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(WEB_PROVIDER_URL)),
)

# Set STARK key.
stark_key_pair_with_y_coordinate = client.onboarding.derive_stark_key()
client.stark_private_key = stark_key_pair_with_y_coordinate['private_key']
(public_x, public_y) = (
    stark_key_pair_with_y_coordinate['public_key'],
    stark_key_pair_with_y_coordinate['public_key_y_coordinate'],
)

# Onboard the account.
onboarding_response = client.onboarding.create_user(
    stark_public_key=public_x,
    stark_public_key_y_coordinate=public_y,
)
print('onboarding_response', onboarding_response)

# Query a private endpoint.
accounts_response = client.private.get_accounts()
print('accounts_response', accounts_response)
```

Comment: I fixed the issue. I downgraded to Python 3.8. Thanks brother